# Printing a webpage with JSF

Tags: jsf, pdf

I have seen webpage with a PDF icon, where you could click on it to print the content of that webpage.

The page i am intending to add the print feature is designed in JSF, so is there anyway where i could add a print button, to get the webpage printed ?

Comment: How exactly is PDF related to this? A PDF file is not a webpage.

Comment: I need to print the content of the webpage as a PDF

Comment: This is then a three-step process. 1) Get JSF-generated HTML. 2) Convert HTML to PDF. 3) Print PDF in browser. You should concentrate on solving the steps individually. If conversion to PDF is not mandatory and just printing whatever you see in webbrowser is sufficient, then it's tremendously easy done by just a single JavaScript function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must do this yourself. Get some PDF library (for example [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)), then get web page output (plain HTML). Then you will have to iterate thru HTML and create PDF version (for example build iText document). You will probably have to do this yourself, because some elements (javascript powered) will need to turn into static content. Nobody but you knows how the output should look like.